# php mysql insert into statement

Tags: php, mysql, validation, insert

When running this code in the web page I do not get a confirmation that it is complete. I took the sql code directly from phpmyadmin sql query window. I would like a little help to this issue. it effects all the add pages.

id

```
$results=mysqli_query($con, "select * from Users where `userName` ='$userName'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
$id = $row['id_cust'];
```

that is before this statement

php

```
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
$artist = $_POST['artist'];
$place = $_POST['place'];
$hour = $_POST['hour'];
$minute = $_POST['min'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$open = $_POST['open'];
$time = $hour.':'.$minute;
$date = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
$result=mysqli_query($con,"insert into Concert values('$id','$artist','$date','$time','$place','$price','$open')");
    if($result)
    {
    echo 'Values updated successfully';
    }
}
```

html

```
<form name="addconcerts" method="post" action="addconcert.php" id="form">
<p>Please Fill out all information</p>
Artist:<input type="text" name="artist" /> <br />
Place:<input type="text" name="place" /><br />
Approximant start time<select name="hour">
<option value="">Hour</option>
<option value="01">01</option>
 """"""""
<option value="24">24</option>
</select>
<select name="min">
<option value="">Minute</option>
<option value="00">00</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="45">35</option>
</select><br />
<select name="month">
<option value="">Month</option>
<option value = "01">January</option>
 """"""""""""""""
<option value = "12">December</option> 
 </select>
<select name="day">
<option value="">Day</option>
<option value="01">01</option>
""""""""""""""""""
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<select name="year">
<option value="">Year</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option> 
</select><br />
Price:<input type="text" name="price"><br />
Opening Act:<input type="text" name="open"><br><br>
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
<input type="submit" name="insert" value="insert">
</form>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where will the variables be inserted? Check this part of your code.
$result=mysqli_query($con,"insert into Concert values('$id','$artist','$date','$time','$place','$price','$open')");

Comment: You should read about SQL injection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @user3517652 the e is not in the original code accidental adding when formatting for the site

Comment: @LoganWayne The variables are in the order they are on the table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `$id` variable is not declared. If `PRIMARY_KEY` and `AUTO_INCREMENT`, remove the variable.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"insert into Concert (id, artist, date, time, place, price, open) VALUES('$id','$artist','$date','$time','$place','$price','$open')");
```

Comment: $id is the primary key for that table, it is also a FOREIGN KEY `is_cust` REFERENCES User (`cust_id`)

Comment: @user3555297 Try passing the fields before `values`. If possible, post the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

**Check Your Insert Query.**

This is your *Insert Query*:

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"insert into Concert values('$id','$artist','$date','$time','$place','$price','$open')");
```

And your *Insert Query* should look like this:

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"insert into Concert (id, artist, date, time, place, price, open) values('$id','$artist','$date','$time','$place','$price','$open')");
```

Of course, you should **REPLACE** the necessary *column names* on the above provided code.

Comment: No "values" are needed?

Comment: Values are still there. You can scroll to the right to see the full code on my answer.